# If $B$ a subring of $A$ and $u$ a unit of $A$ s.t. $u\in B$. Is $u$ a unit of $B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ a ring and $B$ a subring. Let $u$ a unit of $A$ s.t. $u\in B$. Is $u$ a unit of $B$ ? I would say yes, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

**Attempts**

Let $v\in R$ s.t. $uv=1$. I would like to say that $1\in (u)\cap B$, and thus $(u)\cap B=B$. Therefore we would have $k\in B$ s.t. $uk=1$, and since $k\in R$ its also the inverse of $u$ in $R$. Therefore $k=v$.

But I really have doubt with $1\in (u)\cap B$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about $2\in \mathbb Z\subseteq \mathbb Q$?

On the other hand, if $u$ is a unit of $B$ (and $B$ is a unital subring of $A$, I'm assuming) then it is clearly a unit of $A$ (but that is a different question than this one...)

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$, but $5 \in \mathbb{Q}^\times$ and $5 \notin \mathbb{Z}^\times$.